# How to create calculated field in Tableau to return count of instances of value

Tags: calculated-field, tableau-desktop

I'm trying to create a calculated field in Tableau to display a percentage. I have a couple fields that I'm working with: "Record ID" and "Was contact made?" (Yes/No). I want to show the percentage of Record IDs that show up 4 or more times as "Yes" under the field "Was contact made?"

First, I created a calculated field to turn "Was contact made?" "Yes" answers into a 1:

Contact made =1:

```
CASE [Was contact made?] WHEN "Yes" THEN 1 END
```

This calculation to get the percentage:

```
str(countd(if [Contact made = 1] >=4 then [Record ID] end)
/
countd([Record ID]))+"%"
```

When I put the previous calculation in text, it gives "0%", which is not accurate

Answer (score 0):

You could make an LOD calc called **Heavily Contacted?** defined as

```
{ FIXED [Record ID] : SUM(INT([Was contact made?] = "Yes")) >= 4 }
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the type conversion function INT() converts TRUE values to 1 and FALSE values to 0.

One way to get the value you want could then be

```
COUNTD(if [Heavily Contacted?]) then [Record ID] end) / COUNTD([Record ID])
```

That calculation returns a numeric value. I'd just set the default number format for the field to display it as a percentage instead of converting it to a string. (Right click on the field name in the data pane, and look under Default Properties.

With a little more info about your worksheet and problem, you could likely define a field that got the same results without resorting to using COUNTD - as COUNTD can be expensive on large datasets.